# wrong header in bibliography (classicthesis)

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, classicthesis

I'm using classicthesis and have a problem with the header of my bibliography: instead of small caps I receive normalfont letters. I don't know how to make a reproducible MWE, because when I load a bibliography with

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{example}
\bibitem{example}
\bibitem{example}
\end{thebibliography}
```

the problem doesn't occur. And in the classicthesis-package itself, the bibliography is too short to show the problem (header starts at the second page).

So here's what I'm doing:

```
 \documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,footinclude=true, 
            cleardoublepage=empty,
            fontsize=11pt, ngerman,american]{scrbook}
\input{classicthesis-config}

\bibliography{bibliography} % change to your own bibliography
\renewcommand*{\bibname}{Bibliography}
\setbibpreamble{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\part{Introduction}
\include{Chapters/test} % insert chapter with lots of citations

\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}} % work-around to have small caps also
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{\beforebibskip}} % to have the bib a bit from the rest in the toc
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocEntry{\bibname}}
\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

I'm not sure if this is working... if not you might have an idea anyway what I can try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're using `biblatex`, so I removed the call to `natbib` from `classicthesis-config.tex` and added some commands to the preamble:

```
\documentclass[
  twoside,
  openright,
  titlepage,
  numbers=noenddot,
  headinclude,
  footinclude=true, 
  cleardoublepage=empty,
  fontsize=11pt,
  ngerman,
  american,
]{scrbook}
\input{classicthesis-config}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{xampl.bib} % change to your own bibliography

\defbibheading{classicthesis}[\bibname]{%
  \cleardoublepage\phantomsection
  \manualmark
  \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{\beforebibskip}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocEntry{#1}}%
  \chapter*{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\part{Introduction}

% a dummy chapter just by way of example
\chapter{Test}

\nocite{*} % cite everything
\lipsum[1-30]


\printbibliography[heading=classicthesis]

\end{document}
```

The key point is to define a proper bibheading with `\defbibheading`.

### Table of contents

[image]

### Second page of the bibliography, showing the header

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In general this can be done manually, it's useful for getting other lists into smallcaps too, these worked for me (don't forget to reactivate \automark):

```
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\listfigurename}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\listfigurename}}

    \listoffigures

\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
```

and

```
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}} % work-around to have small caps also
\phantomsection 
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{\beforebibskip}} % to have the bib a bit from the rest in the toc
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocEntry{\bibname}}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\label{apen:bibliography} 
\bibliography{Bibliography}

\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using FGiorlando response for Bibliography and Lyx - first use ERT (LaTeX code) and include:

```
    \manualmark
    \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}}
```

Insert Bibliography using Lyx menu Insert List/TOC/Bib(la)TeX bibliography then the following ERT:

```
    \automark[section]{chapter}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}    {\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
```

Just replace \bibname by \contentsname to do the same with Table of Contents:

```
    \manualmark
    \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
```

Insert Table of Contents menu List/TOC/Table of Contents then insert within ERT:

```
    \automark[section]{chapter}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}    {\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
```