# Bibliography headline in capital letters using classicthesis and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, lyx, classicthesis

I use LyX with classicthesis. I just switched from natbib/bibtex to biblatex/biber, because I need some of the functionalities. Everything works fine, but now the word "Bibliography" does not appear as "BIBLIOGRAPHY" in all capital letters in the headline as it should in classicthesis.

How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: Which underlying class are you using and the way you are setting the heading? Can you post a minimal example?

Comment: I think you should still be able to use `\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Bibliography}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Bibliography}}`

Comment: I have to withdraw my last comment. If the bibliography exceeds two pages, only the headline on the odd page is in smallcaps. How do I fix that?

Comment: That was a shot in the dark yesterday, without a compilable example, this will be guesswork. I thought markboth should work, if it does not, i (we) need some information.

Comment: Using your hints in a google search I found [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188126/wrong-header-in-bibliography-classicthesis) thread which perfectly answers my question. Sorry for reopening this topic.

Comment: Great that your problem is solved, we can mark this as a duplicate. If another user on the search for a solution to this topic finds this, it is linked in a very obvious way to the solution.